# I can't add plugin to my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I can't install a plugin to my wordpress site, the add plugin menu is not showing. Previously, I was still able to install the plugin normally, but after returning to the admin page after a while, I could no longer install the plugin.

Hosting and domain accounts are all managed by me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is no space left on your server for new plugins or the file permissions are incorrect.